# Xulrunner - Google Analytics doesn't recognize visit

Tags: google-analytics, xulrunner

My app opens a specific website link in an iframe but GA doesn't recognize a visit. It recognizes it OK in NW.js, if I open it directly in the browser, ...

I've tried to make a Mobile App account but it doesn't help.

Do I have to set some preferences in xulrunner to make this work? If so, what preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should check the iframe and browser tag in xulrunner. You are probably using iframe tag to start the application, i had the same issue. Just use the browser tag and you will be ok.

EDIT TO EXPLAIN A BIT MORE : 
iFrame tag - An inner frame that works much like the HTML iframe element. The src attribute can be used to specify the content of the frame. This content is a separate document.

browser tag - A frame which is expected to contain a view of a Web document. It is similar to an iframe except that it holds a page history and contains additional methods to manipulate the currently displayed page.

When you use iframe tag, google requires you to make additional changes so the tracking works ok. More info : goo.gl/sZz9Mk

Comment: Thanks it helped :) Whats the difference between those two tags? Why does it not work with the iframe tag?

Comment: iFrame - 
An inner frame that works much like the HTML iframe element. The src attribute can be used to specify the content of the frame. This content is a separate document. 

browser - 
A frame which is expected to contain a view of a Web document. It is similar to an iframe except that it holds a page history and contains additional methods to manipulate the currently displayed page.

When you use iframe tag, google requires you to make additional changes so the tracking works ok.
More info : https://goo.gl/sZz9Mk